# CSS Hover to change other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, nav

I have this navigation bar which I have done in CSS, I would like it so when I hover over one of the 3 navigation icons it will change the main image background position.

I've tried a few ways but not managed to get them to work properly.

**CSS**

```
    /* Nav Button 1 */

.nav1 {
    float:left;
    padding-top:20px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}

#nav1
{
  display: block;
  width: 92px;
  height: 107px;
  background: url("images/triangle.png") no-repeat 0 0;

}

#nav1:hover
{ 
  background-position: 0 -107px;
}


/* Nav Button 2 */

.nav2 {
    float:left;
    padding-top:20px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

#nav2
{
  display: block;
  width: 92px;
  height: 107px;
  background: url("images/triangle.png") no-repeat 0 0;

}

#nav2:hover
{ 
  background-position: 0 -107px;
}

/* Nav Button 3 */

.nav3 {
    float:left;
    padding-top:20px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

#nav3
{
  display: block;
  width: 92px;
  height: 107px;
  background: url("images/triangle.png") no-repeat 0 0;

}

#nav3:hover
{ 
  background-position: 0 -107px;
}

/* Nav Name */

.navname {
    float:left;
    padding-top:20px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

#navname
{
  display: block;
  width: 228px;
  height: 81px;
  background: url("images/blank.png") no-repeat 0 0;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="nav1">
    <a id="nav1" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav2">
    <a id="nav2" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav3">
    <a id="nav3" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navname"><a id="navname" href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how this can be done? The 'navname' element is background position I want to change when hovering over either nav1, nav2, nav3.

Thanks :D

Comment: Unless you want to change the element itself, or a child of the element, you would have to use Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite simple using jQuery:

```
$('element-to-initiate-change').hover(function(){
    //this will happen when your mouse moves over the object
    $('element-to-change').css({
        "property":"value",
        "property":"value",
    });
},function(){
    //this is what will happen when you take your mouse off the object
    $('element-to-change').css({
        "property":"value",
        "property":"value",
    });
});
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dLbDF/258/

If you made a jsfiddle using your code, I would've done this to your code so you could see clearer. Always use jsfiddle or some other kind of example when asking a question.

Comment: Hi, here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/gacBC/1/
The 'main' image is that brown looking rectangle

Comment: No, *he's given you the answer*. You need to apply the answer to your own code.

Comment: @Alex I'm using CSS background for the images not the <img> tag.

Comment: Okay, I see what you wanted. I did this: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkKramer/gacBC/5/ I used `.mouseover` instead of `.hover` for the first since you didn't need a seperate function to fire on mouseout. But for the other two I used .hover and made the background position move back to the top on mouseout.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but here's a possible CSS-only solution for others who come across it.

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/ancwqda3/

html

```
<div id="navigation">
    <a class="nav n1" href="#"></a>
    <a class="nav n2" href="#"></a>
    <a class="nav n3" href="#"></a>

    <a class="title t0" href="#"></a>
    <a class="title t1" href="#">one</a>
    <a class="title t2" href="#">two</a>
    <a class="title t3" href="#">three</a>
</div>
```

css

```
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 92px;
    height: 107px;
    background: url("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/693779/triangle.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}

.nav:hover { 
  background-position: 0 -107px;
}

.title {
    width: 228px;
    height: 107px;
    background: url("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/693779/blank.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    color: red;    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;    line-height: 107px;
    text-align: center;
}

.t0 {
    display: inline-block;
}

.t1, .t2, .t3 {
    display: none;
}

.nav:hover ~ .t0 {
    display: none;
}

.n1:hover ~ .t1, .n2:hover ~ .t2, .n3:hover ~ .t3 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```